# Submit a form according to the choice of the button radio

Tags: php, radio-button

I am building an ecommerce web application for School Education.
The customers have a choice between three payment methods. Let's Say Paypal, Moneybookers (Skrill) and Alertpay. That means: each product must have three "Buy Now" Buttons. Here are examples of these buttons:

PAYPAL

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="payment@mail.com">
<input name="submit" >
</form>
```

ALERTPAY

```
<form action="https://www.alertpay.com">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="payment@mail.com">
<input name="submit" >
</form>
```

MONEYBOOKERS

```
 <form action="https://www.moneybookers.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="payment@mail.com">
 <input name="submit" >
 </form>
```

My purpose is to just have one "Buy Now" button in front of each product.

After clicking that button, the customer is redirected to a page where they will have to choose one payment method by selecting it with the radio button.

After their selection, they will submit their choice by clicking on a button and according to their choice, will land to Paypal or Alertpay or Moneybookers website.

I am a novice in PHP and I know this is possible, but I don't just know how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assign each form an Id. For example

```
<form id="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="payment@mail.com">
<input name="submit" >
</form>
```

Then set the radios value to Form Id. For example

```
<input type="radio" name="payMethod" value="paypal" class="paymentMethod" /> PayPal<br />
<input type="radio" name="payMethod" value="aleartPay" class="paymentMethod" /> Alert Pay<br />
<input type="radio" name="payMethod" value="moneyBookers" class="paymentMethod" /> Money Brookers<br />
```

Then do following on button click

```
var selectedMethodId = $(".paymentMethod:checked").val();
$('#'+selectedMethodId).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one page where the selected radio button changes the `action` of the `<form>` then you're either going to need to:

- Submit the page to the server on selection of a radio button. The returned form has the required `action` value.
- Use some JavaScript to set the `action` attribute when a radio button is select. This avoids waiting on a new page to load.

But the latter method does require a little code to handle the radio button selection event, and you need to consider if you want to support users who have disabled JavaScript.